# Override AWS SDK Endpoint for AWS Step Functions Local

Tags: testing, mocking, aws-step-functions

I want to test my AWS Step Function state machine with AWS Step Functions Local (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local.html), where I mock specific AWS Service operations via a faked HTTP Server as endpoint.

AWS Step Functions Local in general works just fine; I can create & start the state machine successfully.

But I use some (Service-)Tasks that utilise the generic AWS SDK Client (e.g. CodeCommit) rather then "optimised" Tasks (e.g. DynamoDB).

The endpoints for the latter can be overridden, e.g. by Environment Variables for docker (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-config-options.html).

But I see no option to override the "generic" AWS SDK endpoint, thus AWS Step Functions Local uses the *actual* AWS Endpoints (`https://{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com`), which is not what I want.

Does anyone know *if* this can be achieved in some way?
Or, if not, maybe this feature can be requested somehow?

Cheers!